# Rescued European sparrow has a weird pimple

Tags: health, birds, skin-condition, anatomy

I rescued a baby European sparrow that fell into my garden (its parents didn't come back).
It is doing fine and slowly learning to fly, scavenge for food, etc.

When it took its bath I noticed a strange pimple on its rump (see the picture).
Is it something to worry about?

The pimple in question:

[image: European sparrow rump pimple]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The „pimple“ is a normal part of the bird’s anatomy, it’s the [uropygial or oil gland](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uropygial_gland) and it produces the oils necessary to waterproof and care for his plumage - think of it as nature’s conditioner.

Usually the gland is barely noticeable, because it’s hidden in the feathers. I am no vet, so I can’t judge whether the appearance is as it should be (it differs a lot between various kinds of birds). It appears a bit “full” (the cushion like bit, the “nozzle” is fine), which can happen at times. Please watch your foster baby for a bit and if he shows any signs of discomfort or the gland grows, contact a vet. As a general guideline, ensure that he gets all his vitamins (especially vitamin A) and a balanced diet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the infos and the care advices !